# Question about equivalence relation/bitstring

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, bit-strings

[image]

Actually i have no idea about this question.i know the definition of equivalence relations 1-) reflective 2-) symmetric 3-) transitive but not more :(

Comment: OK,but, do you know what "reflexive" means? what "symmetric" means? what "transitive" means? If you do, what happens when you try to apply your knowledge to the two questions? (if you don't, well, that's where you should begin!)

Comment: For question b) "belong to the same equivalence class of 01100" means here "have the  same number of ones as 01100" : this is not a really difficult question, don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

OK, so you know the definition of an equivalence relation ... That it needs to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive ..  so just appl those definitions to this specific relation $R$:

Reflexive: Any bit string $x$ has the same number of $1$'s as $x$ itself.

Symmetric: If bit string $x$ has the same number of $1$'s as bit string $y$, then $y$ has the same number of $1$'s as $x$

Transitive: If bit string $x$ has the same number of $1$'s as bit string $y$, and bit string $y$ has the same number of $1$'s as $z$, then bit string $x$ has the same number of $1$'s as bit string $z$

Second question: Two bit strings $x$ and $y$ are in each other's equivalence class if and only if $xRy$, i.e. if and only if they have he same number of $1$'s.

Comment: This OP wants his work to be done by others: look, he has asked 5 questions in 8 hours, this one being especialy significant of a lack of work. He should be warned that Math SE has not to be used that way.